Metrics that weighs under forecasting and over forecasting differently
I have multiple moving averages forecasts that use different look back periods. I’m measuring accuracy using MAPE. Out of all the options, I want to select the best performing moving average. However, I want to penalize under forecasting a little more than over forecasting because the business risks are significant if we under forecast. Obviously MAPE is not allowing me to do that. Are there any methods that allow me to do this?

I recommend you first think about what you are forecasting for. Which business decision will your forecasts support? From your description, it sounds like you want to set capacities, including safety capacities.
For this, it makes most sense to require quantile forecasts, i.e., you want to forecast a number such that the true outcome has a chance of (say) 80% to come in under that number. The tool of choice to elicit quantile forecasts is the pinball loss. The best paper on this is Gneiting (2011).
However, moving averages do not aim at quantile forecasts. If you assess different moving averages using pinball losses, you are essentially looking which moving average does the worst job at what it is trying to do, which is an expectation forecast. Much better to use standard forecasting methods (see Resources/books for project on forecasting models for resources) and derive quantile forecasts directly from them.
